# Data propagation between server instances GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

On 06/06/2013 our Application on GAE had a strange behavior.
We have a counter similar to the transactional one that you [suggest](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions?hl=pt-br)
where we do a search on an entity by a numerical value, get a number and increment, then record it in our entity
to be used as a unique identifier for our business object.

On this day during this process the counter returned the same number twice at an interval of 1 hour, causing insconsistence in our application.

Trying to identify what was the root cause of the problem, we noticed that there was a MemCache problem - "Service disruption" at the same time according to the api dashboard: https://code.google.com/status/appengine/2013/06/06

Our question is whether this problem https://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/memcache/2013/06/06#ae-trust-detail-memcache-get-latency could affect the data propagation between our server instances:

```
instance = 00c61b117cb53bffbf575a4fbd3c87274a9ac6
instance = 00c61b117c67b34229139a32e9e4e61fdfcd9b3a
```

This information is very important for us to identify the root cause of the problem
and we would be very grateful if you could help us.

Comment: Log a issue with google. ALso look through the groups, it seems other apps had similiar issues.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/lnuDtviiKgg  and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/0oG0HlY8tjs